# How to use Butterknife to get a reference to the fragment xml

Tags: android, android-fragments, butterknife

Is it possible to get SomeFragment via an interface? I don't want to use FragmentManager, because in my original code MainActivity is a fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.some_container)
    FragmentCallback fragment;

    public interface FragmentCallback {
        void test();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragment.test();
    }
}

public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCallback {

    public SomeFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle
            savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_some, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {
        Log.d("" , "it works");
    }
}
```

layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/some_container"
            android:name="com.tamtam.myapplication.SomeFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.tamtam.myapplication, PID: 29138
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.tamtam.myapplication/com.tamtam.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void com.tamtam.myapplication.MainActivity$FragmentCallback.test()'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'void
>   com.tamtam.myapplication.MainActivity$FragmentCallback.test()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   com.tamtam.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's not possible because**

A `Fragment` is not a `View`, Butterknife's `@BindView` is used to bind a View, not a Fragment.

You can use `FragmentManager.findFragmentById(int id);` to get a fragment, but if you check the implementation, you'll see that `FragmentManager` doesn't look in the `View` hierarchy

```
public Fragment findFragmentById(int id) {
    if (mAdded != null) {
        // First look through added fragments.
        for (int i=mAdded.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            Fragment f = mAdded.get(i);
            if (f != null && f.mFragmentId == id) {
                return f;
            }
        }
    }
    if (mActive != null) {
        // Now for any known fragment.
        for (int i=mActive.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            Fragment f = mActive.get(i);
            if (f != null && f.mFragmentId == id) {
                return f;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**If you want to do this with ButterKnife**

You could extend ButterKnife by adding this functionality, or you could just create a wrapper around it and look for your own annotation. For example, you could create a custom annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BindFrament {
    @IdRes int value();
}
```

create a wrapper with `bind(Activity)` method, call `ButterKnife.bind(Activity)` method and then look for your own annotation and set it to the instance field

```
public class ButterKnifeWrapper {

    public static void bind(Activity activity){
        ButterKnife.bind(activity);

        Class clazz = activity.getClass();
        for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()){
            if(field.isAnnotationPresent(BindFrament.class)){
                Class fieldType = field.getType();
                if(Fragment.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldType)){
                    int fragmentId = field.getAnnotation(BindFrament.class).value();
                    Fragment fragment = activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragmentId);
                    try {
                        field.set(activity, fragment);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your activity you could then do this

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindFrament(R.id.my_fragment)
    MyFragment myFragment;

    @BindView(R.id.my_view)
    View myView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        ButterKnifeWrapper.bind(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx @lelloman this is what I was looking for. Butterknife should have this functionality by default :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add fragment runtime.

Here is an example for you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Fragment1 fragment1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragment1 = Fragment1.newInstance();
        }
        displayFragmentHome();
        // Now you can call your fragment's method
        fragment1.test();
    }

    private void displayFragmentHome() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (fragment1.isAdded()) { // if the fragment is already in container
            ft.show(fragment1);
        } else { // fragment needs to be added to frame container
            ft.add(R.id.frame, fragment1, "HOME");
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements FragmentCallBack {

    private View mView;

    public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
        Fragment1 homeFragment = new Fragment1();
        return homeFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        TextView mText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        mText.setText("Welcome..");
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

**FragmentCallBack.java** your interface

```
public interface FragmentCallBack {
    public void test();
}
```

This way you can call interface's method in your fragment from your activity.